# cannot alter update option in TDengine database?

Tags: tdengine

I know that there are 3 update options in TDengine database:

- 0: data cannot be updated
- 1: update entire row
- 2：update some column

If I create a database with update option equals to 1, why I cannot alter this option to 2

```sql
taos> create database db update 1;
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.007480s)

taos> alter database db update 2;
DB error: Invalid database options (0.000722s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update option is special, it is not allowed to be updated once the database is created.